# Accessing Array Values in other instances

Tags: arrays, xcode

In my application, I am trying to access the array values but the array is return zero values. I have been stuck on this for a few hour now, and cannot seem to solve it. So any help would be appreciated:

```
@implementation MyScene{
 NSMutableArray *_touchPoints;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self.scene];
    [self clearTouchPoints];
    [self addTouchPointToMove:touchPoint];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self.scene];
    CGPoint targetPoint = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x , touchPoint.y - delta.y);
    [self addTouchPointToMove:touchPoint];
    NSLog(@"Value: %lf", touchPoint.y);
}

- (void)move:(NSNumber *)_tempTime{
    CGPoint currentPoint = [_touchPoints[0] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint targetPoint = [_touchPoints[1] CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"Check Value: %lf", targetPoint.y);
}

- (void)addTouchPointToMove:(CGPoint)point {
   [_touchPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
}

- (void)clearTouchPoints {
   [_touchPoints removeAllObjects];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is never initialized (e.g., `_touchPoints = [NSMutableArray new];`) so it is `nil`. Attempting to invoke methods on a `nil` object does nothing, nor does it complain (i.e., does not throw an exception). So in the `addTouchPointToMove` method:

```
[_touchPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
```

does nothing.

In the `init` method, initialize the array.